# Mongoose TypeError: applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am getting an error after running a simple javascript code with mongoose.
This is the error:

```
const alreadyHookedFunctions = new Set(applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap(fn => ([fn, `$__${fn}`])))                                                                  
TypeError: applyHooks.middlewareFunctions.flatMap is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Apeksha\Documents\MERN\mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\model\applyHooks.js:29:71)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Apeksha\Documents\MERN\mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:31:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

This is my `script.js` file

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const User= require('./User')

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/testdb",
()=>{
    console.log('connected')
})

async function run(){
    const first_user= await User.create({
        name: 'Apeksha', 
        roll_no: 124, 
        city: 'Mumbai'
    })
    console.log(first_user)
}
```

This is my `User.js` file

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose')

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    roll_no: Number,
    city: String
})

module.exports= mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
```

I tried reinstalling mongoose, with `npm i mongoose`, I can't seem to figure out what went wrong in the code.

Comment: What version of Node are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mongoose version 6.8.4, which requires node version 16 or above. Since, in Ubuntu 20.04 (my system), default version of node will be 10.19.0 (So I am encountered the same error at first). Try to update your node or use the same version of node by downgrading your mongoose to version 5.